# Ubuntu 18.04 Intel i5 4-Cores peaking one at a time

Tags: 18.04, cpu-load, intel-cpu

I'm having an issue with different programs making my quad-core i5 peak. Not sure exactly what to do. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Image of System Monitor]

Update: I was able to break it down to the “gedit” program. It drives my cpu all the way up so it won’t let me download VMware or use some programs

Comment: Look at the Processes tab. Looks like you have a single thread process running all the time which consumes a whole core. This re-scheduling of the process between different cores every now and then is normal behaviour.

Comment: It seems to be doing it whenever I open applications like Alice 3 or try to download VMWare